# UICollectionView in storyboard not scrolling

Tags: storyboard, uicollectionview, swift2, ios9

I am presently working on an app, It still early days into the development. I have a login screen and after successful login, the user will be presented with a collection view. The cellSize is (280,140) for the iPhone. So with this size in the iPhone portrait, I can see cells arranged in the below way
[image]
Also there should 2 more cells which will be created as soon as I start scrolling, but the UI seems stuck and I am unable to scroll. 
As soon as I change the orientation to landscape here, I can scroll and see all the 6 cells, but still the the left column seems unresponsive and I can only scroll from the right one.

[image]
I am using storyboards, FlowLayout and this ViewController is UICollectionViewController subclass.
This might be a very silly question but I am badly stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was not a collectionView issue, It was because of a loading indicator which didn't got nullified.